# Avec un jeu de mots, pourrait-on dire : « il n'y a pas le feu au resto (ou : au cinéma) » ?

Tags: expressions, jeux-de-mots, humour

Une amie à moi semblait brûler d'envie de déjeuner à la va-vite pour nous rendre au cinéma alors que je voulais qu'on déguste d'abord plus de mets au resto.

Pour exprimer l'idée de « Pourquoi tant d'empressement ? Qu'est-ce que ça te coûte de faire un sort aux plats savoureux, tranquillement ? », je me demande si j’aurais pu dire, avec un petit jeu de mots plutôt qu'avec le mot attendu « lac » :

---

> Il n'y a pas le feu **au resto** !

... au sens de « Le resto, ***où on est en train de déjeuner***, ne risque pas de s'enflammer, loin de là ! Alors pas besoin de t’empresser de le quitter ! ».

> {ou bien} : Il n'y a pas le feu **au cinéma** !

... au sens de « Le cinéma, ***notre prochaine escale***, ne va pas prendre feu de sitôt ! Du moins, pas avant qu’on y ait regardé un film... Inutile donc de te dépêcher ! ».

---

Bien entendu, je pourrais très bien me contenter de ne pas y ajouter de mots supplémentaires, mais je me suis dit que quitte à utiliser l'expression exagérée « il n'y a pas le feu », autant en faire quelque chose d'unique en son genre en fonction du lieu ***où on se trouve*** ou ***où on va***.

Comment: Il me semble qu'*"il n'y a pas le feu au lac"* se réfère à l'endroit où l'on se trouve actuellement qu'on n'aurait pas besoin de quitter précipitamment, ce qui exclut d'emblée la seconde proposition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Il n'y a pas de règle pour les jeux de mots. C'est un peu comme la licence poétique pour l'écriture en vers...

Cela dit, celui-ci n'est pas terrible, *à mon gout.*
L'humour de "il n'y a pas le feu au lac" vient de l'idée absurde qu'un lac rempli d'eau puisse bruler. Tandis qu'un restaurant qui brule, c'est plausible, et l'effet absurde est raté.

Comment: +1, ou alors une absurdité au second degré provoquée par le détournement d'un jeu de mots drôle pour en faire un pas drôle. *"Y a pas le feu au restaurant ! ... hahaha."* Faire sarcastiquement des blagues très mauvaises peut être amusant en soi :)

Answer (score 1):

Une plaisanterie possible au restaurant avant le cinéma serait de dire "on a le temps, le cinéma ne va pas refroidir", dans la mesure où c'est une expression qui s'emploie précisément pour les plats servis chauds. (Je ne sais pas si c'est la meilleure plaisanterie de l'année, elle reste cependant dans l'esprit recherché, avec une touche d'absurdité).

Answer (score 1):

Un lac est composé d'eau, laquelle sert notamment à éteindre les incendies.
De là l'expression “il n'y a pas le feu au lac” qui indique que le lac n'étant pas susceptible de s'enflammer, il n'y a pas urgence à prendre la fuite pour s'en éloigner.

De par sa nature, un restaurant est beaucoup plus susceptible de prendre feu, et pour ma part je n'oserais pas prendre le risque de défier le destin avec votre boutade : je crois à la malchance et à la justice immanente, deux raisons pour ne pas tenter le diable.

“Il n'y a pas le feu !” suffit, évitons de dire où.

Answer (score 0):

The expression "Il n'y a pas le feu au lac!" is often shortened to:

> "Il n'y a pas le feu!"

In this case, rather than choosing in between "restaurant" and "cinéma", I'd just have used the short form, without the not-so-funny-imho joke.